I'm trying to check the Bulk 2.0 Ingest Job status. Now my integration is failing due to isPkChunkingSupported field in the response
I'm trying to check the Bulk 2.0 Ingest Job status. Now my integration is failing due to the isPkChunkingSupported field in the response. Below is a sample response.
{
    "id": "750J3000002cXp1IAE",
    "operation": "insert",
    "object": "Account",
    "createdById": "0055i000008JnfPAAS",
    "createdDate": "2024-08-09T15:38:07.000+0000",
    "systemModstamp": "2024-08-09T15:39:06.000+0000",
    "state": "JobComplete",
    "concurrencyMode": "Parallel",
    "contentType": "CSV",
    "apiVersion": 61.0,
    "jobType": "V2Ingest",
    "lineEnding": "CRLF",
    "columnDelimiter": "COMMA",
    "numberRecordsProcessed": 1,
    "numberRecordsFailed": 0,
    "retries": 0,
    "totalProcessingTime": 300,
    "apiActiveProcessingTime": 215,
    "apexProcessingTime": 54,
    "isPkChunkingSupported": false
}

Now, my integration is failing as the new boolean field isPkChunkingSupported is coming in response and it differs from the AsyncApi schema JobInfo element.
This issue is seen from Version 60.0 onwards.
How to overcome this issue?
I need a schema or any reference as a source of truth.
Please throw some light on the issue.
Thanks.

Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read How to Ask and take the tour. Including a Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example would be helpful. integration is failing...is differing the AsyncApi schema JobInfo element and I need a schema or any reference as source of truth are contradictory statements.
